# Where is HasDefaultValue() extension method on Entity Framework Core 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

This line is warning error whem moving to EF 3.0, I can't find the  HasDefaultValue() extension method

```
using MGame.Core;
using MGame.Model;
using MGame.Model.Enums;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using System;

namespace MGame.Data.DataContextConfigurations
{
    public class AddressConfiguration : DataContextBaseEntityTypeConfiguration, IEntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Address> builder)
        {

            builder.Property(e => e.AddressTypeId).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(0);
```

also fails with

```
        builder.ToTable(nameof(AncestorRegionView));
```

and also with

```
builder.Metadata.IsQueryType = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add a reference to the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.0.0" />
```